# How to check Send Message permission of bot in my Discord Channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

This is my code:

````
```
if (message.user.bot.permissions.has("SEND_MESSAGE")) {
        console.log("I can send message!!")} 
else {
        console.log("I can't send message!!")
}
```
````

For exp: I want to check bot permission in channel ID: 988087516844421170
What should I do?

Comment: Forgot my bot ID: 986945043849945088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check bot permission in channel you should use [`Channel.permissionsFor()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseGuildTextChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor) like in this code:

```js
if(message.channel.permissionsFor("BOT_ID").toArray().includes("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
// code if has permission
} else {
// code if no
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use `toArray()`. `Permissions` class has a `has()` method for this.